# How do I fix it when the SSIS designer pane goes white?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I've had a long-standing problem that every so often, when I open an SSIS package (2012), the designer pane is blank (all white).

If I try to view the code, it comes up, but the file name in the tab shows up as blank.

If I try to execute it, I get a message saying "Unexpected internal error: " -- and nothing else.

Rebuilding doesn't seem to help.

Unloading / Reloading the project doesn't help.

If I try to save the file, I get an error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Closing the entire application usually does the trick, but when I have dozens of packages in one solution, it's brutally slow.

I've noticed one other fix, which is to rename the package, which is obviously not ideal... but it does seem to indicate that the name of the package is what's causing the problem. If I rename the package back to the original name, the problem re-appears.

I've also tried deleting the metadata for the graphical rendering, but that doesn't do anything either.

Curious if anyone has seen this problem and has a solution. I saw nothing helpful online.

Comment: The only trick that works for me is closing and reopening SSDT.

Answer (score 2):

For me this problem was resolved in two simple steps below.

1. Rebuild the Project.
2. Close Visual Studio & reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but this is a common thing I run into and I want to make sure its answered.

1. Open the package that gives you the white screen.
2. While open, rename the package (suffix it with 1).
3. Close the package.
4. While closed, rename the package back to the original name.

This has worked every time for me.